# angular 2 md-select select option by keyboard

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, keyboard, material-design, angular-material

In Angular Material docs `md-select` has keyboard interaction: `up arrow` to select previous option, `down arrow` to select next option, `space/enter` to select option which is currently focused on.

But is there any way to make a new option be selected while pressing `up arrow` key or `down arrow` key without pressing `space/enter`?

I thought about some kind of custom directive, which can be applied to `md-select`, but on my page `<md-select></md-select>` element is replaced by another html from angular material package.